# properties resolving order in parent-child context

Tags: spring, configuration

Given: application context that is created in runtime, having its own properties that are runtime-dependent aswell, and its parent application context, with own properties and  placeholder configurer.

Problem: child context instantiation with link to parent comes to placeholder resolving at moment of instantination, what is not acceptable for me at all, since child's environment isnt configured yet.

i.e. further code crushes on instantiation:

```
    ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
            new String[] { descriptor.getContextFilePath() }, parentContext);

    StandardEnvironment env = new StandardEnvironment();
    Properties props = descriptor.buildProperties(...);
    PropertiesPropertySource pps = new PropertiesPropertySource("endpointContextProps", props);
    env.getPropertySources().addLast(pps);
    context.setEnvironment(env);
    context.refresh();
```

I found working solution for it, that suppose to set up parent context not on initialization, but after all required environment is set:

```
    ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
            new String[] { descriptor.getContextFilePath() }, false);

    StandardEnvironment env = new StandardEnvironment();
    Properties props = descriptor.buildProperties(...);
    PropertiesPropertySource pps = new PropertiesPropertySource("endpointContextProps", props);
    env.getPropertySources().addLast(pps);

    context.setEnvironment(env);
    context.setParent(parentContext);
    context.refresh();
```

however Im not satisfied by fact i should know the order of my actions and should keep in mind how placeholder configurer works inside context creation. 
I wonder if there's more neat way to get my context work?